# Propagating error when taking the derivative

Tags: standard-deviation, error, uncertainty, error-propagation, derivative

I have a function that corresponds to a set of $(X,Y)$ coordinates with a Gaussian uncertainty ($\sigma_Y$) for each point. What I want to do is now compute the gradient of this function and the uncertainty associated with $\frac{dY}{dX}$. But given $X, Y, \sigma_Y$, and $\frac{dY}{dX}$, how does one compute $\sigma_\frac{dY}{dX}$?

Here is a simple working example where I compute $\frac{dY}{dX}$ using the gradient operator:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt 

def f(x):
    """arbitrary function; I won't always know its exact functional form a priori"""
    return 1.5*(1. - np.tanh(100.*(x-0.96))) + 1.5*x*(x-0.95) + 0.4 + 0.01*(1.-x)* np.random.random(x.shape)

X = np.linspace(0.8,1.1,1000)

# Observations and noise
y = f(X).ravel() 
sigma = 0.2/y + 0.1*(1.-X) 

plt.figure()  
plt.plot(X, y, 'k-', label=u'mean')
plt.fill(np.concatenate([X, X[::-1]]),
         np.concatenate([y - 2. * sigma,
                        (y + 2. * sigma)[::-1]]),
         alpha=.1, fc='k', ec='None', label='2 standard deviations')
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')  
plt.legend(loc='lower left')
plt.show()

dydx = np.gradient(y)/np.gradient(X) 

plt.figure()  
plt.plot(X, dydx, 'k-', label=u'dy/dx') 
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('dy/dx')
plt.legend(loc='lower left')
plt.show()
```

[image: (X,Y) data plotted with uncertainties]
[image: (X,dY/dX) data plotted without uncertainties]

I have $\sigma_Y$ and plotted it accordingly, but how can I compute $\sigma_\frac{dY}{dX}$, i.e. the uncertainty for the gradient? Is there any additional information necessary?

Note: I only know the values of the function numerically and would be computing the gradient numerically as well. My only expectation is that the function should be always differentiable, but the magnitude of the gradient could be quite small or large in different areas of the domain, although the data comes from a physical source which constrains it to be smooth. Additionally, the exact source of $\sigma_Y$ (Gaussian error) is unknown to me, it was provided by a black box that is no longer available for reference. I simply have these $\sigma_Y$ and know they correspond to a single standard deviation.

Comment: Estimating the derivative requires adopting a specific model for this function.  So far, there's no assurance the function is even differentiable! Since you don't have a particular functional form in mind, you have to be particularly careful, because you need *some* way to constrain the possible values of the derivatives--some requirement on the degree of smoothness of the function.  Is there anything about the underlying statistical problem that would suggest some such constraint?

Comment: Yes, in this instance, I only know the values of the function numerically and would be computing the gradient numerically as well. My only expectation is that the function should be always differentiable, but the magnitude of the gradient could be quite small or large in different areas of the domain. To clarify, I should be able to estimate the derivative itself numerically. But how does one estimate the uncertainty of the derivative numerically?

Comment: There are various ways to make that estimate, but under the broad conditions you have given, the uncertainty in any such estimate will be infinite, because there's no way to distinguish actual variation in the underlying function from the random noise.

Comment: I do expect the variation in $Y$ (i.e. which I should've denoted as the mean function) to represent the actual variation of the underlying function. Maybe I am still missing your point on what additional information is necessary, and further clarification on this problem would be helpful.

Comment: One way to make progress would be to clarify the nature of what is known.  In particular, how is $\sigma_Y$ known?  Does it need to be estimated from these data; has it been estimated from other data; or is it perhaps given by theoretical considerations?  Regardless, consider the family of functions $h_{\epsilon,n}:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ given by $$h_{\epsilon,n}(x)=\epsilon\sin\left(\frac{nx}{\epsilon}\right).$$ Suppose the true function is $f.$ For $|\epsilon|\ll \sigma_Y,$ $f$ and $f+h_{\epsilon,n}$ will be indistinguishable. However, for large $|n|$ the latter will have huge derivatives.

Comment: What assumptions can you make to rule out this kind of function as a possible solution?

Comment: The exact source of $\sigma_Y$ (Gaussian error) is unknown to me, it was provided by a black box that is no longer available for reference. I simply have these $\sigma_Y$ and know they correspond to a single standard deviation.

Comment: That is an important point and thank you for expanding on it. My underlying assumption is that $\mathbf{E}[Y] = f$, which is the black line that I have displayed in the first plot. It is possible the derivatives may be large, but that is taken to be representative of the true function's derivative. Also, the physical data I am considering will never permit very large $\lvert n \rvert$ due to the inherent smoothness of the physical data. Given this, what would be the steps to estimate $\sigma_{\frac{dY}{dX}}$?

Comment: The nature of the information you have related (so far) invites us to contemplate a solution that fits a function to the data in a way that makes trade-offs between (1) achieving a smooth fit, (2) yielding residuals with variance close to $\sigma_Y^2,$ and (3) achieving an accurate fit. The ideas underlying *smoothing splines* may be useful in approaching this, but at some point you will need to apply some judgment in making these trade-offs. The derivative of the fitted function will depend on those judgments and the uncertainties in the values of the derivative will depend *heavily* on them.

Comment: At this point, please consider incorporating the additional information you have supplied in these comments into an edit to your post so that all readers will more readily grasp what your problem is.